# How to make student work in think-pair-share?

Tags: undergraduate-education, classroom-management, classroom-interaction

I have been trying the [think-pair-share](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/3/11702) technique in my undergraduate linear algebra class of about 30 students. Some students quite enjoy the experience. But I noticed that some other students simply use the time to check their cellphones or do what-ever they want.

I am picking a random student to share the answer now. But since we have a large class, it is unlikely that one is chosen. So many of them just take the chance and ignore the exercise.

Should I pick the students who clearly do not work on the problem instead?

Comment: Collect everyone's work without announcement, that may change the dynamic.

Comment: Do the students know each other, or are they complete strangers? Many answers in the linked question reference safety as a success factor in encouraging participation. Are you doing anything else to develop that atmosphere?

Comment: They do know each other. Though a few students don't talk with any one.

Comment: Forced groupwork does not work. Why American educators are so hung up on it is beyond me.